# fuction() not working in Detailview yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, detailview

When i am going to show user details in Detailview than it throws:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Below is my code for Detailview:

view.php

```
        <?= DetailView::widget([
                'model' => $model,
                'attributes' => [
                    'userID',
                    'userEmail:email',
                    'userName',
                    'userMobile',
                    'userBirthDate',
                    'userGender',
                    [
                      'attribute' => 'interestName',
                      'format' => 'raw',
                      'label' => 'Interest',
                      'value' => $model->getUserinterest(),
                    ],
                      'userStatus',
                      'userType',
                ],
         ]); 

 ?>

 function getUserinterest() { 
           foreach ($model->userinterest as $userinterest) {
                $interestNames[] = $userinterest->interestName;
            }
        return implode("\n", $interestNames);
    }
```

Comment: What's your Yii2 version?

Comment: Yii2 version is : 2.0.10

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Follow the final answer as below:

view.php

```
 <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'userID',
            'userEmail:email',
            'userName',
            'userMobile',
            'userBirthDate',
            'userGender',
            [
                'attribute' => 'interestName',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'label' => 'Interest',
                'value' => $model->getviewinterest(),
            ],
           'userStatus',
           'userType',
        ],
    ]); 

 ?>
```

Users.php(Model)

```
public function getviewinterest() 
    { 
        foreach ($this->userinterest as $userinterest)
            { 
                $interestNames[] = $userinterest->interestName; 

            } 

            if(!empty($interestNames)){
                return implode("<br/>", $interestNames);
            }else{
                return "(not set)";
            }
    }
```

Comment: @Yupik Follow this final solution

Comment: okk right as you say. It's work fine as per your method as well as my method also.

Comment: Please, don't use framework if your method is "fine" for u. How about additional SQL queries in your method? How about memory? How about 16 lines of useless code? U getting paid for lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.0.11 `value` can be defined as closure. Upgrade Yii version to developer version 2.0.11+ and it will work.

Comment: It's not a stable version yet. I have verified it on github 90% of work has been done for release. [link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/milestone/20)

Comment: That's true, thats why i said "developer version" :)

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: 1. Wait for official relase 2.0.11   2. Don't use closure, create function in model, and use it like `'value' => $model->getMyBlaBla()` or `'value' => $model->myBlaBla` if u named function `getMyBlaBla()`.

Comment: Edited my code as you say now it throws:  **Object of class yii\db\ActiveQuery could not be converted to string**

Comment: `getUserinterest()` is in your model or view file?

Comment: I am using the concept of juction table I got it from model and i want to show it in a detailview as well as gridview. I have done with gridview. Now i want to show it in detail view. The method Useinterest is already exist in model.

Comment: Thats why u have exception like this.... Put it in model with diffrent name, actually ure trying do display your relation in DetailView. Function in view will give u nothing.

Comment: Exacly what i said: Create function in model:    `public function getMyBlaBla() { 
            foreach ($this->userinterest as $userinterest) {
                $interestNames[] = $userinterest->interestName;
            }
        return implode("\n", $interestNames);
    }`, and then use it in DetailView `'value' => $model->myBlaBla,`

Comment: Thank you so much as per your given idea i have done it in a different way.

Comment: Can u share how u did it?

Comment: I have given the solution please follow it.